# joining html header, body and trailer using Python

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to join htm header with the body and trailer like this

```
    message1 = """<html>
<head></head>
<body><p>"""
message2 = 'Hello World!'
message3 = """</p></body>
</html>"""

html_message = join(message1,message2,message3)
```

but when I print "html_message" the result is "\Hello World!\", why themthe backslashes appear , how could I remove

Comment: Wait, how does this even work? Are you using a library or something?

Comment: yes ----- from os.path import basename,join----

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you are using a (wrong) imported method, but you can use the percent operand with strings

```
template = """
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>%(text)s</p>
  </body>
</html>
"""
html_message = template % {"text":"Hello World!"}
```

Don't forget, the variable name format is: percent sign + name in parentheses + format (s for string)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would join the string:

```
message1 = """<html>
<head></head>
<body><p>"""
message2 = 'Hello World!'
message3 = """</p></body>
</html>"""

html_message = "".join([message1,message2,message3])
```

The `join` you are referring to merges files together, which are usually in the form `Something/another/thing`, hence the back slashes. No need for `from os.path import basename, join`

Answer (score 0):

To join strings, use the `+` symbol

```
html_message = message1 + message2 + message3
```

`os.path.join` is used to create file path like `os.path.join('my', 'script.py')` => `my/script.py`